# Adding different text fields in each category footer using enhanced custom categories plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I have been trying for hours to display an advanced custom field in the footer area in order to change the category text according to each category.
As soon as I leave the scope of the content-ecp.php file, the category ID changes.

When using the `$product_cat_id` in `the_field('content_under_products', $product_cat_id);?>` to retrieve the field data..

I don't get the correct ID where the field content is stored. The correct ID would be (1034) but I am getting (108). 
I know, I could change the code to `the_field('content_under_products', 1034);?>` but this would only work for one specific page which wouldn't make much sense side-wide.

There must be a way to select the other ID. Unfortunately, my knowledge of php is very little. So I didn't manage to come up with a proper solution with a dynamic post ID.

I would be extremely glad if anyone could help me out with this.

Here is a link to the page : https://praesenteente.de/geldgeschenke/
I basically consists of:

CATEGORY HEADER AND DESCRIPTION (here, the field can be displayed correctly)

WOOCOMMERCE PRODUCTS

FOOTER (here, it doesn't show up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you only have access to your $product_cat_id inside the content-ecp.php file.

I think there is a logic issue you should check: The content-pages are for single views, so when there is an id for a single post/page and you want to have them look the same for all single posts.

An archive page is viewing a collection of posts. The name of your variable PRODUCT_cat_id using not the plural of products, lets me assume you are setting the value of the variable like this:

```
$product_cat_id = get_the_ID();
```

So the id of the current viewed post is saved to the variable.
This is working fine in a single page, but not in archives.

When you are viewing a category, you have an id for the term you are viewing. For example the category is called "category" and you are now viewing "shoes", which is a category term. You can get the id of the term of the current viewing category term page by using:

```
$cat_term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

Now you have saved the id of the category term. With this id you can now get your category description text, which is a meta field in your category term.

```
$cat_description = get_field('content_under_products', $cat_term_id );
```

This is working, if your 'content_under_products' field is an field added with acf to categories. I think this is what you are looking for.

If I got your question wrong and you just want to show the description for the archive itself (and not for the terms of the category / taxonomy), you can just use:

```
$archive_description = get_the_archive_description();
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_description/

Comment: Thank you so much!!

The archive description field is what I needed to fetch the content (which the enhanced category plugin already displays in the header) and basically duplicate part of it after the woocommerce content, in the footer.

It's embarassing to admit but it took me 1,5 days to figure out these two lines of code.

`<?php 
$archive_description = get_the_archive_description();
the_field('content_under_products');
?>`

I really need to start learning php and wordpress structure from scratch...